# Dispatcher ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, task

I am learning about cross threading and have a question regarding how I can update the main UI thread from a class I have created (viewmodel).  From what I have gathered, the dispatcher is the way to go.  How do I use the Main UI threads dispatcher in a class?  Or is there a better way to do this. In this example I am databinding a textblock to the Count Value.  What would I need to do to get this to work.  Thanks!

```
class customVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChange(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set {
            _count = value;
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Count));
        }
    }

    public async void methodAsync()
    {
        await method();
    }

    private Task method()
    {

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                //*************
                Count = i;
                //*************
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: unclear question, in the code posted, normal binding will work. what else you are trying to do?

Comment: Count is binded to the textblock.  Cross threading occurs.

Comment: Never mind, I guess cross threading works without directly using a dispatcher in WPF applications.  Im moving between different platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to dispatch `PropertyChanged` from another thread to UI thread, as the `PropertyChanged` event is automatically marshalled to the UI dispatcher.

```
private Task method()
{
    //The following code is okay. There is no need to marshal it explicitly        
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            //*************
            Count = i;
            //*************
        }
    });
}
```

As a [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630646.aspx) says:

> Note that in WPF, things are different and the code shown in Figure 5
>   works even if the Status property is data-bound to a TextBlock. This
>   is because WPF automatically dispatches the PropertyChanged event to
>   the main thread, unlike all the other XAML frameworks. In all other
>   frameworks, a dispatching solution is needed.

**However, it is only true for change notifications on scalar properties** (i.e. `PropertyChanged` event). Collection change notifications (`INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event) don't work that way, they must be raised on the UI thread manually. That is, when using `INotifyCollectionChanged` (such as with an `ObservableCollection`), these changes are not marshaled to the UI thread. This means that if you modify collection from non UI thread, you’ll take an exception. We’re in the ViewModel class and we don’t use the Dispatcher to update UI. So I advise to you to use David Rickard's approach:

```
public static class DispatchService
{
    public static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        Dispatcher dispatchObject = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        if (dispatchObject == null || dispatchObject.CheckAccess())
    {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatchObject.Invoke(action);
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
DispatchService.Invoke(() =>
{
    this.MyCollection.Add("new value");
});
```

[David Rickard article at msdn blog.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidrickard/2010/03/31/using-the-dispatcher-with-mvvm/)

Answer (score 2):

Cross-threaded scalar property binding only works on WPF (and possibly also Xamarin). It does *not* work on other MVVM platforms.

Your code appears to be a kind of progress report. The appropriate solution is `IProgress<T>` with `Progress<T>`:

```
class customVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int _count;

  public int Count
  {
    get { return _count; }
    set {
      _count = value;
      OnPropertyChange(nameof(Count));
    }
  }

  public async void methodAsync()
  {
    var progress = new Progress<int>(count => { Count = count; });
    await Task.Run(() => method(progress));
  }

  private void method(IProgress<int> progress)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      progress.Report(i);
    }
  }
}
```

`Progress<T>` works quite nicely with all UI platforms, including ones with different types of dispatchers, and even non-MVVM ones such as WinForms.